# jQuery UI Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, themes

When I try to download the jQuery UI theme I get the following message: 'Error 502 Ray ID: 5971b498fc66e047 • 2020-05-21 22:24:04 UTC
Bad gateway'. On GitHub they say it's had this problem for over 8 months. How do I get the jQuery UI theme? Can I get it from someplace else?

Comment: You can get it here: https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: Results in "Error 502". See [https://github.com/jquery/download.jqueryui.com/issues/359](https://github.com/jquery/download.jqueryui.com/issues/359).

Answer (score 0):

You can build one locally.

I followed following [step](https://github.com/jquery/download.jqueryui.com/issues/359) and [step](https://github.com/jquery/download.jqueryui.com).

Exact steps outlined in the README did not work for me. So I had to modify a bit. Here they are:

```
Step 1: I have ubuntu 18 and process did not work for me. Installation of ImageStick failed at make install due to error blob.c file. So I downloaded VirtualBox and installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS.
Step 2: Download node-v7.10 (version 12 did not work for as npm failed)
Install following two pacakges as these are needed for grunt prepare:
Step 3: sudo apt-get install libxml2
Step 4: sudo apt-get install xsltproc 
Following is needed for ImageStick with PNG=yes:
Step 5: apt-get install libpng-dev
Step 6: Download and install ImageMagick-6.9.11-30. Only this version worked for me. Ensure with-PNG is YES as mentioned in the readme.doc.
Step 7: git clone download.jqueryui.com-2.1.16. Do not use master.
Step 8: npm install
Step 9: grunt prepare
Step 10: node server.js --console
Step 11: goto localhost:8088
```